# Rails: How to automatically query for items that belong to user in session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm developing an app with `Rails 3.2.11` and I'm using Devise and CanCan.

I'm setting permissions in the `ability.rb` file so the user can only manage items that belong to his company, and everything seems to work just fine.

- My User model `belongs to` a Company model.
- This Company can `have many` Clients models.

I was wondering if there is a way to automate my queries with a scope or gem or whatever so every time I fetch via `Client.all` it only returns the clients that belong to the user's company, or if I call `Order.all` it shows only de orders for his company clients.
Is this posible? If not, what would be the best approach?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you want Client.all to return only clients those belongs to user's company, then it seems to be wrong. As per my understanding `Client.all` should always return all the records in clients table. You can create a method in User model or you could directly query `current_user.company.clients`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding, but what about writing a method?

If you want to fetch the users clients (which belong to the users company)

user.rb

```
def fetch_clients
  Clients.find_all_by_company(company) # your query here
end
```

in your controller you could simply:

```
@clients = @user.fetch_clients
```

and the same goes for orders

Thanks to  SybariteManoj, he pointed out that (assuming your queries are not more complex):

```
@user.company.clients should return the same result
```

Comment: Why would I create another method since I have associations in place? Wouldn't `@user.company.clients` return the same result?

Comment: Yeah it should I will add your comment to the answer, but I was not sure what OP meant with "is a way to automate my queries", I thought he might have additional/more complex queries. ty

Comment: @SybariteManoj I think I'm going to use that approach. Thanks both for your replies ;)

Comment: No Problem. :) I just wanted to make sure we follow the main rule of rails 'convention over configuration'. :)

Answer (score 0):

CanCan has something called `accessible_by`. Could that be what you are looking for?

Read more here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records